# Bootstrap 3 navbar issue with logo

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Having an issue with bootstrap3 responsive navbar and a logo - it displays fine on a desktop and works fine.  When on a mobile and collapsed, I can click the button, but the menu doesn't show up - just a horizontal scroll bar.  I am stuck.  Here is my HTML code

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap links -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-left" href="#">
          <img src="" alt="logo" id="sitelogo" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="what-we-do.php">What We Do</a></li>
          <li><a href="case-studies.php">Case Studies</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Could we get a static public link to the image, or could you tell us the image dimensions, please? A local image isn't of much use for us.

Comment: 432px by 118px in desktop, 250px by 118px in mobile - removing the image and just using text results in same issue

Comment: Your code works. Perhaps you forgot to include jQuery like I did with the previous edit.

Comment: Not missing jquery, can do a $(document).ready( ... just fine, it's so weird - could it be that I'm not using the bootstrap theme?

Comment: Possibly, if you've not got the core document I don't think the twitter variation will work. This is purely speculation - I don't use Bootstrap. Try adding each of the links I did and hopefully that will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `height: auto!important;` to `#navbar` and remove `position: absolute;` from `#navbar .nav` and that should fix the problem.

Comment: Oh thank you so much, I was ripping what little hair I have left out!  I knew it was something silly.  Upvoting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried removing

```
aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"
```

Comment: This does not fix the problem